# Ошибка java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter

Tags: java, apache, post

Хочу отправить фотографию POST-запросом, используя библиотеку HttpClient от Apache.
Вот класс, в котором я делаю запрос (запрос выполнен по документации https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-multipart-upload#addpart):

```
public class PostCall extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                File filePhoto = new File(mainPhotoUriStr);
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uploadUrlWithoutBracketsWithSlashes);
                FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(filePhoto, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);
    
                MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                builder.addPart("file", fileBody);
                HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    
                post.setEntity(entity);
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

На строке HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); вылетает ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
    Process: com.example.shoptest1, PID: 18085
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:365)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter; in class Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:53)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:72)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:84)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:494)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:149)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:138)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:726)
        at com.example.shoptest1.CreateProduct$PostCall.doInBackground(CreateProduct.java:164)
        at com.example.shoptest1.CreateProduct$PostCall.doInBackground(CreateProduct.java:161)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

В gradle, для подключения библиотеки было добавлено:

```
dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6'
    api 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
}
```

Не подскажите, как пофиксить данную ошибку?

Comment: Возможно, нужно там возвращать не null, а строку.

Comment: @Ansar Ozden, проблема в том, что до строки return null программа не доходит - крашится на при создании клиента (описано выше).